# Setting up a dynamic hostname with a local IP?

Tags: networking, dns, ip

I'm on a university network, so I don't have any control of the routing settings and the sort. That being said, I do have the perks of having fairly fast speeds, especially within the network. I have taken full advantage of this by using remote desktop regularly.

However, I no longer have a static IP and am instead on a dynamic one. How do I broadcast this local IPL Could I register a local hostname? Or maybe email it to myself whenever it changes?

(I am running windows 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could script a way to obtain your IP, save it to a .bat file, set up a scheduled job to run every X hours, then output the IP to a location such as Dropbox or Google Drive.  That way, you can always access the txt file wherever you are and get the current IP.

You can also sign up for a service such as [NoIP](http://www.noip.com/) to assign a domain name (usually `foo.noip.com`).  Then, when you want to access your computer, just use the domain name.

Comment: I tried using NoIP but it seems like it broadcasts my global, not local, IP

Comment: @randomafk ah, yeah.  I didn't know you weren't public-facing.  My college opened that all up so we could use that solution.

Comment: just set it up with this bat script! http://superuser.com/a/230326/122491

Answer (score 0):

You could make a pretty simple python script that checks your local IP and emails (or texts) you if it changes.  The downside is this way, you'd need to do a task scheduler to run it (as with most ways with scripts).

You could get the local ip in Python with:

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname( socket.gethostname() )
```

You could use that to save the latest known IP to a file, and check the new IP verses the IP in the file and email you if it's different (and obviously update the old file).

I have a python script I use to do the email using gmail's SMTP servers through a dummy account [here](https://github.com/nerdwaller/server_scripts/blob/master/py_mailer/py_mailer2.py) on Github.

I think socket and email are both in the standard library for [Python](http://www.python.org/).

This will work cross-platform if python and the modules are installed.

Comment: I was thinking of doing this, and probably will. Was hoping for a cleaner solution. but thanks1

Comment: Yeah, I haven't found any great ways to do it on a local network.  Used to have a similar problem back when I was in school too - python was the easiest way to work cross-platform for me.  I do like @Kruug's idea of just syncing that file to a dropbox/drive/other folder.

Comment: just set it up, more convinient that emails I think.