# Batch script to only run command for 1 machine

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, group-policy

I have a Windows GPO that runs a batch file startup script to disable NetBIOS.  It normally looks like this:

```
wmic nicconfig where (TcpipNetbiosOptions!=null and TcpipNetbiosOptions!=2) call SetTcpipNetbios 2
```

However, I just found out that I have one particular computer that needs NetBIOS enabled.  I didn't want to make an entire new GPO for this one machine and I also wasn't sure if it would override the other one, which is global.  Excuse my Pseudo-code, but How can I make it so this command will only execute if the computers IP is not a certain one?

```
IF(<This IP Address> != 192.168.1.1)
wmic nicconfig where (TcpipNetbiosOptions!=null and TcpipNetbiosOptions!=2) call SetTcpipNetbios 2
```

Or is there a better idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get LAN ip to a variable in a Windows batch file](http://superuser.com/questions/230233/how-to-get-lan-ip-to-a-variable-in-a-windows-batch-file) + `IF NOT "%IP%"=="192.168.1.1"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the computer's hostname be sufficient, instead of IP Address?

```
IF %COMPUTERNAME% NEQ NetBIOSPC (wmic nicconfig where (TcpipNetbiosOptions!=null and TcpipNetbiosOptions!=2) call SetTcpipNetbios 2)
```

Obviously, replace `NetBIOSPC` with the actual hostname of the system. Be sure you're using the right hostname by typing `hostname` or `echo %COMPUTERNAME%` at the local CMD prompt on the target system.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  Would this work?   IF NOT "%IP%"=="192.168.1.1" (wmic nicconfig where (TcpipNetbiosOptions!=null and TcpipNetbiosOptions!=2) call SetTcpipNetbios 2)

Comment: I wouldn't personally use `IF NOT x == y` where `IF x NEQ y` would be equally effective, but that's just a matter of personal preference. The only way you can use `%IP%` as an element in your conditional statement is if you have by some means already assigned the system's IP address to that variable - it is not a built-in environment variable, like `%COMPUTERNAME%` is.